# Linux Luks encryption automount and unmount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, encryption, mount

I have a Luks encrypted external hard drive that I have setup to auto-mount and auto-unmount after rsync. I have the system put the encrypted file to be mounted under

```
/dev/mapper/foo
```

Anyway, im not sure what you would call the state that it is in where it is under the /dev/mapper/ folder but, my question is, while it is in that folder and not yet mounted, is it un-encrypted? or only when it becomes mounted?

Furthermore, if someone where to  take the external while it was mounted, would the data be encrypted?

System: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
Device: USB hard drive, external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to answer as posted - it's worthwhile understanding the concepts which, once understood, will provide the knowledge you are after.

Linux has a concept of block devices which can be either physical disks, partitions or virtual structures. Further - and this is important - drivers can be used to create layers / abstractions of underlying devices - and this is key to how LUKS works.

When you use Like, it takes a block device, adds an abstraction/control layer and presents another block device which is unencrypted.  This means that if the LUKS key has been loaded into memory and LUKS has unlocked the drive it can be read in it's unencrypted state even if it's not mounted. ( This is useful and necessary, as it allows you to use your preferred filesystem type on it, or even LVS to provide multiple volumes and other functionality - because all LUKS is doing is taking a block device input and creating a block device output).

This also means that if the USB drive is removed - even while in use - its still encrypted (and unusable without the key) as the key and translation is in memory on the PC, not the disk.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just started using LUKS encryption, and im figuring out what to do to get from A to Z but it will take me time to find out why and how it gets there. As I understand your answer, when it is in the /dev/mapper folder it is in a state where it can be read, although in non specific format, and when it is mounted, it is put into a file system format i.e. ext4, am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: More-or-less, yes. A filesystem is a way of dividing a disk to make the files findeable, so you "format" the /dev/mapper device with your desired filesystem. Mounting the device simply provides a seemless mechanism to access the data on the filesystem as part of the larger linux filesystem.